# How to avoid looping through strings as arrays in C?

Tags: c

In this example, I am trying to match the integer literals with the types[] array. Technically, the printf() should be printf("The variable %c = %d (%s) \n"), but gives an error if I don't specify types[i] as a character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

extern int ints[];
extern char strs[];
extern char types[];
extern void intro();

int ints[] = {
  212, 215u, 0xFeeL, 07, 032U, 85, 0213, 0x4b, 30, 30u, 30l, 30ul  
};

char strs[] = {
  'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'  
};

char types[] = {
    "decimal",
    "decimal unsigned",
    "hexadecimal long",
    "octal",
    "octal unsigned",
    "decimal",
    "octal",
    "hexadecimal",
    "decimal",
    "decimal unsigned",
    "decimal unsigned",
    "decimal unsigned long"
};

int main(){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 12; i++){
       printf("The variable %c = %d (%c) \n", strs[i], ints[i], types[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void intro(){
    printf("------\n");
    printf("Looping through these results \n");
    printf("------\n");   
}
```

I am sure there's something simple I am missing on this to anyone experienced in C.

Thanks!

Comment: That's because the type of `types[]` is `char`, but its values are `char[]`. I will let someone correct me here, but if there is one thing string literals like "decimal" in C aren't, it's `char` -- that's just enough to hold a single `char`, as the name suggests. The type should be `char[]` or `char *`, because that's what a string is. You have an array of pointers to `char` -- your `types` has to be declared as `char* types[]`. In fact, your code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: I like how `0xFEEL` looks like.

Comment: @amn Ok... meaning code-wise?

Comment: @amn -- "its values are `char[]`": string literals do have type `char[]`, but decay to `char *` in most expressions. Yet here there is UB due to mismatch between the type of `types[]` and the initializer list members. If `char *types[] = { ...` then the string literals will decay to `char *`, but if `char types[][MAX_LEN] = { ...` then the string literals will remain `char []` and be used to initialize the arrays in `types [][]`.

Comment: What error does it give? Wouldn't it be good to a) paste the error message into the question, and/or b) google this error code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done a silly mistake. The mistake is that your types[] array is an array of characters rather than an array of strings.

A char is:

```
char types = 'a';
```

An array of chars is:

```
char types[] = {'a', 'b'};
```

A string is:

```
char types[] = "hello";
```

and also:

```
char *types = "hello";
```

An array of strings is:

```
char *types[] = {"hello", "world"};
```

What you intended to do is:

```
char *types[] = {
    "decimal",
    "decimal unsigned",
    "hexadecimal long",
    "octal",
    "octal unsigned",
    "decimal",
    "octal",
    "hexadecimal",
    "decimal",
    "decimal unsigned",
    "decimal unsigned",
    "decimal unsigned long"
};
```

Now you can change your printf to:

```
printf("The variable %c = %d (%s) \n", strs[i], ints[i], types[i]);
```

Comment: That's it! Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You want an array of strings (`const char *`) and not characters (`char`), i.e:

```
const char *types[] = {
```

With that in place, you won't get any warnings/errors regarding the `%s` in your printf (which should be in there).

Answer (score 0):

```
"decimal"
```

This is a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal). It's type is `char[]`, it's an array of characters. An array of types in most contexts decays (read: atomagically changes) into a pointer to type.

```
char a = "decimal";
```

This is invalid code, but usually compiles with a single warning. Here the string literal is converted into `char*` type, a pointer to char. Then the pointer to char *value* is converted into a char *value* (thus it's removing information from it, as usually `sizeof(char) = 1` is way smaller then `sizeof(char*)`).

```
char a[] = { "decimal", "blabla", };
```

The same happens over and over again. The `char*` pointer *value* is converted to a char value. This can be maybe more verbosely represented by (assuming CHAR_BIT=8):

```
char a[] = { 
        (char)((uintptr_t)(char*)"decimal") & 0xff), 
        (char)((uintptr_t)(char*)"blabla") & 0xff), 
 };
```

What you want is an array of string literals. You can achieve that by storing an array of pointers to string literals, ie. array of `char*` pointers, ie. `char*[]` type.

```
const char *types[] = {
    "decimal",
    "decimal unsigned",
    "hexadecimal long",
    "octal",
    "octal unsigned",
    "decimal",
    "octal",
    "hexadecimal",
    "decimal",
    "decimal unsigned",
    "decimal unsigned",
    "decimal unsigned long"
};
```

Or you can store the strings:

```
char types[][ /*MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRING*/ 128 ] = {
    "decimal",
    "decimal unsigned",
    "hexadecimal long",
    "octal",
    "octal unsigned",
    "decimal",
    "octal",
    "hexadecimal",
    "decimal",
    "decimal unsigned",
    "decimal unsigned",
    "decimal unsigned long"
};
```

ie. this is a double array.

Note: string literals are immutable, modifying them is undefined behavior (read: don't do it).